# как оставить предыдущую картинку в BD Если при update не была загружена новая или не удалена ? Laravel, PHP

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            
            if ($image) {
                $imagePath = ImageController::store($image);
            }
        $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
    
        $product->image = $imagePath ?? '';
        
        $product->save();
}

class ImageController extends Controller
{
    public static function store($image) {

        $input['imagename'] = time().'.'.$image->extension();

        $destinationPath = public_path('/storage/uploads');

        $img = Image::make($image->path());

        $img->fit(200)->save($destinationPath.'/'.$input['imagename']);
        
        return 'uploads/'.$input['imagename'];
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну как минимум наверное вести отдельную таблицу с картинками с мэни ту мени к моделям. Получаете список картинок и берёте последнюю

Comment: @Walfter  получается удалять через ajax ? или как то добавлять через js в поле image deleted и только после сохранения удалять?  чтобы если ничего не загружено то оставить предыдущую если она есть если удалить то удалить, если добавить то добавить